# We should be able to find questions or answers that we have deleted

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I deleted one of my questions and would like to undelete it. This requires finding the question.

I think you shouldn't be prevented from seeing your own posts that you have deleted. It should be easier than me remembering the link or checking the browser history to easily look these up.

I would currently need 10K to see my deleted items and even then if I can find their URL.

Comment: A page showing my own deleted questions and answers would be useful. And I'd like it to show my answers to a deleted question too. It's very annoying if the OP deletes his question and my answer disappears with it.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41130/can-we-have-an-isdeleted1-search-option-operator and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50237/add-advanced-search-option-for-finding-deleted-posts

Comment: Why has this not been implemented yet?

Comment: If I had to guess, it's because it's tagged as [status-bydesign]  I guess if we could all build things that suck and say we meant to do it and then never had to fix it, we'd all be better off.

Comment: place a bounty of 500... that'll draw attention

Comment: I think that it's excessive exaggeration to say that Stack Overflow "sucks" just because this aspect of the system doesn't work the way you expect it to.  There's no need to be rude, or demanding (as you are being in your edit) when making feature requests.

Comment: Attention doesn't correleate to action in this context. The devs aren't exactly falling over each other to earn those rare, valuable MSO rep bounties.

Comment: @PopularDemand I'm fully aware of that... ;)

Comment: @jadarnel27 - I'm not being rude.  Remember a working principle of stackoverflow is to make the internet a better place.  Earth day was yesterday and we can't recycle our own deleted posts...  Just saying...

Comment: RE: Your bounty reason: Looks like it's tagged [meta-tag:feature-request] to me...

Comment: See, I told you a bounty would draw attention =)

Comment: LOL...  Declined FTW...  So nice to accept a crappy design!

Comment: [Since June 2013](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile/185492#185492), deleted questions and answers that were posted in the past 90 days, can be seen using the "deleted recent questions" and "deleted recent answers" links on the questions and answers tabs in your user profile.

Comment: (I've added the same reference to Marc's answer; you might consider accepting that for future readers?)

Comment: This was the duplicate?

Answer (score 38):

[Since June 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile/185492#185492), deleted questions and answers that were posted in the past 60 days can be seen using the "deleted recent questions" and "deleted recent answers" links on the questions and answers tabs in your user profile.

In February 2020, this was expanded to posts deleted in the past 60 days, including those posted more than 60 days ago.

In [January 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374184/241919), the 60-days restriction was removed, and the links were changed to "Deleted questions" and "Deleted answers". All users can now see all their deleted questions and answers.

> [image]

<sup>Prior to that, non-moderator 10k users couldn't see their deleted posts from their profile page either, though they could (and still can) search for them by using `deleted:1`.</sup>

Comment: No, deleted questions are not visible on the profile page for non-diamonds.

Comment: doesnt seem like this works anymore

Comment: For *self-deleted posts* looking at [deletion votes on the profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=deletion) should work too. (This tab contains also delete votes cast on other users' posts, but that is only relevant for 10k+ users and they can [search using deleted:1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145060/enable-searching-with-deleted1-for-10k-users).)

Answer (score 26):

We need an **isdeleted:** operator for the search box, so that deleted posts can be searched.  It would search them all for 10ks, and user-only posts for specific users under 10k.

Comment: The latter point wouldn't be... too useful. Answers it'd find, but sub-10k users still can't see their own deleted questions.

Comment: @Grace, I mean for them to be enabled to see their own deleted questions.

Comment: It's called `deleted:` and it exists for 10k+ users: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327259/6083675

Comment: @Laurel, Thanks, glad they finally added that feature.

Comment: Can this answer be completed to something giving full details of what it refers to?

Answer (score 10):

If you're looking for a particular deleted post *that you own*, feel free to email us and we'll find it for you. Our email address is at the bottom of every page.

Comment: Yeah thanks...  But what about the posts that you simply can't find.  Know you left it, but just don't know where it went?

Comment: Mind putting a `status-bydesign` or some official response on this question?

Comment: That’s inconvenient at best. A lot of people got multiple questions nuked due to the various “clean-ups” like the anti-identify cleanses. Some people may not care, while others may want to extract their questions to post elsewhere. Having to search the Wayback Machine and trawl through history files, hoping to find them at all, or even directly emailing staff is a poor solution. Worse, that would require actually *knowing exactly* which questions one had asked that have been deleted instead of just looking at the question/answer lists in the profile page (and ideally clicking a filter).

Comment: Writing to Mods just to find my own post? Why wasting everyone's time for what can be automated?

Answer (score 9):

You should still be able to see your own deleted answers - just find the question and it should be there, in a different colour.

You can then edit it (like I'm doing now - this answer is deleted at the time of editing) and click undelete when you're ready.

I'm testing it here as I have under 10K rep here...

(Just tried it on SU and I've been able to see it there too.)

EDIT: Just tested with a deleted question - it didn't show up in either the question list or my recent activity.

Comment: Perfectly visible here ;-p I'm wondering if you'll get "taxonomist" for [delete-me] ;-p

Comment: you have over 10k rep here

Comment: @Benny: I do *now*... but presumably I didn't back in August 2009.

Comment: How can I find the question if I only remember keywords from my answer? There would be thousands of questions with that keyword, so can I filter them?

Answer (score 5):

It's been said repeatedly on Christianity SE that deletion is not a death sentence. Deleted posts should be edited, fixed, and undeleted. This is hard to do if you can't find the things.

Comment: That's closed questions, not deleted ones. Closed means that there's a chance to fix them. Deleted are things we're quite certain should go away.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your browser history.

Other than that, the only way currently is to get 10k rep and look through the list of recently deleted posts. The list actually goes clear back to [the first question on the site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1), so yours will be in there *somewhere*.

Comment: I've been tempted to scrape it, but I don't want to abuse the site or my account. However, if *someone* manages to get a dump of the deleted posts, I'd be very interested in getting a copy.

Comment: There's only 5000 pages...

Comment: Just take it slow, run a cron job scraping 10 pages an hour. It won't change that rapidly. I'm very interested in the list as well, but have no means of obtaining it.

Comment: That would be very interesting. You could profile exactly what kind of mistakes the community makes.

Comment: @Kyle - that would be a **lot** of "asdf" and "Win32/google-groups" posts ;-p

Comment: @mmyers: Well I was thinking more of the posts themselves than just the titles, but I suppose that would be valuable in its own right

Comment: So deleted posts are included in the dump? I suppose there's no point in hiding them.

Comment: @mmyers: no, they're not - I would like to see them included though. That's why I'm interested in an unofficial scrape of the deleted posts - I want a better way to search and find them than simply stumbling upon them or going through a 5000 page list

Comment: A simple search like user:myuserid deleted:1 sure would be handy.

Answer (score -1):

Find a full list of your own activity using `user:55747` in the search box. However, the deleted posts will only appear if you have 10K rep.

Right now there does not appear to a flag for deleted posts, so you'll have to scroll through them all...

Comment: It would be nice if the background colour in the search page used the deleted colour (the purplish tone). But alas.

Comment: @dmckee how might I go about finding what number I should enter for my own activity?

Comment: @MitchellCarroll Hover over or click on your own user name...your ID number is part of the URL for your profile page. But it appears that you need 10k rep for this to be useful. I'd forgotten.

Comment: @dmckee, Deleted posts **do not** show up on that list, even if you scroll through everything.

Comment: You should've mentioned directly in the answer that it's for 10k users only. Yet this answer is obsolete anyway, since 10k users now can use `deleted:yes`, and for regular users deleted posts do not show up in the search, even their own.