# Allow users to be able to see their own deleted questions

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions

I've just stumbled across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887273/declaring-variables) poorly worded question - if you look through the comments it appears that the user previously asked an identical question that was deleted - it occurred to me that this question may well have been deleted before the poster had a chance to read any of the comments / feedback on that question, and may not have even realised that his question was deleted (hence the identical repost).

I'm not sure if this feature already exists or not (being that I've never had any of my questions deleted), but it strikes me it might be a good idea to allow users to see their deleted questions, and hence maybe learn why their question was deleted.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/how-do-i-find-questions-or-answers-that-ive-deleted

Comment: This isnt really a duplicate - my point is that users who have their questions deleted should have it made visible to them why their question was deleted.

Comment: While the linked post mentions a feature request to see deleted questions, it ended up tangential to the actual content - no one in the answers actually addresses the viability of the feature-request, and an answer to the actual title question was discovered. I think this makes more sense to reopen as a separate question than try to bog down the linked question (which is great as a support question).

Answer (score 4):

> I've just stumbled across this poorly
>   worded question

If the question was poorly written chances are it may get closed.
But before the question is closed the user will be notified by other users that the question needs more details.

If the user does not pay attention to those comments and does not improve the question it is likely to get closed.

> if you look through the comments it
>   appears that the user previously asked
>   an identical question that was deleted
>   - it occurred to me that this question may well have been deleted before the
>   poster had a chance to read any of the
>   comments / feedback on that question,

This looks like a rare occurrence, as the user might come back to check if any answers are posted.
If the question is closed he will get to know that the question is closed.

But in the case of having a deleted question instead of having a dedicated page as "My deleted questions" in the profile page as [stefan](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/158652/stefan) suggested, the user can see the deleted question in the list of questions on the profile page marked in gray or red indicating that this question is deleted.

Also the user should be able to view the deleted question.

And when the user views the deleted question he gets to see a message displayed with the question indicating the reason the question was deleted, similar to the message shown for the closed questions.

Comment: I don't mean to offend but I don't think you're quite understanding what this request is about. This is about *deleted* questions, not *closed* questions. Members with at least 10k rep (and moderators) can *already* see *all* deleted content. Other members can see their own deleted *answers* as well, but there's no way to get to the *question* if it's deleted. This particular question was *already* closed a long time ago *and deleted* by the *community*, not the original author, so he really had no choice in the matter.

Comment: @Aarobot My answer was about deleted questions not closed questions,I have updated the answer. I think I didn't phrases the sentence well.

Comment: This still isn't making any sense.  Even the very first sentence ("if the question was poorly written chances are it may get closed") seems to be oblivious to the fact that this question was already closed and deleted ages ago, and the last sentence is just not how the system works - there is no "reason" for deletion, if a question is deleted then the deletion reason would be implied by the close reason.

Answer (score 4):

I was just reviewing my questions, and stumbled on a [deleted question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311018/convert-binary-data-to-double-in-classic-asp) almost by accident. I linked to it from [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310639/reliably-convert-a-string-to-a-double-independent-of-regional-settings-in-classic). I removed the link now, but if I hadn't put it there, I would never have known my question was deleted.

I also still don't know **why** it exactly got deleted. It would be nice to at least **get notified** if a post you wrote gets deleted.

It just occurred to me: I might even have deleted the post myself. I just don't remember. So it would be welcome if we saw our own deleted questions when logged in. Just like we can see our own deleted answers.

Comment: You deleted it yourself - it says so at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @ChrisF: Thanks to let me know... seems my memory is degrading fast :-s

Answer (score -4):

I think it can be solved by adding "My deleted questions" in the profile page.

Comment: Removing the "hand over the bounty please" made me remove my down vote.

Comment: @stefan Yeah, being better than the masses, *and* specific "ownages" really sucks. It gets boring at times. That's why I've decided to destroy the Earth. See ya'll. (You're going to have to wait until December 21, 2022.)

Comment: @muntoo it's ok, all of us not being deceased have left earth anyway. say hello to sebastian while you're still there!

Comment: @stefan *You* may have left it, but ~7 billion (other idiots :) ) haven't. BTW, Sebastian told me to tell you to "eat my code", whatever that means.

Comment: @muntoo ok, i still beat him chess

Comment: @stefan He says he's better at checkers. (Although chess is way better, IMO.)