# See a deleted question? (or at least know why it was deleted)

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Allow users to be able to see their own deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32675/allow-users-to-be-able-to-see-their-own-deleted-questions)
>   [Why was my bug report deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35899/why-was-my-bug-report-deleted)

I have had quite a few of my questions deleted today  :(

One of them (from StackOverflow) I understood, two of them (from Meta) I don't get why they were deleted.

The latest casualty was more significant.  I posted a bug (admittedly a minor bug, but still a bug).

Now there is no trace of it.  No reason why, nothing.  No trace at all.

Is there some way to find out why it was deleted?

And why does something like a bug report get deleted anyway?  If needed, close it.  Buy why erase it from existence?

Comment: That possible duplicate contains a broken link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today, if the bug report or any of the meta posts were related to the server crash, they probably got deleted from the powers above. Mainly because they weren't really constructive, and server failures happen.

For the other questions, chances are you won't be able to find out why they were deleted. Because the questions have no visible trace (as they were deleted), you can't really link to them to see if anyone remembers deleting the question. And I'm pretty sure people with 10,000+ reputation can't see the questions either.

Unfortunately, that is the about as much information as I can give you. If a moderator sees this post, they might have a little more insight on the situation, but my guess is that the Meta-Deletions were due to the StackOverflow Team.