# How can I see a deleted question of my own?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

I want to see my deleted question. How can I reach it?

> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161185/racist-negative-votes#comment468033_161185

Comment: Upvote this [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) so that one day you will maybe be able to see your deleted questions.

Comment: Probably duplicate of several questions, such as: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35908/see-a-deleted-question-or-at-least-know-why-it-was-deleted?rq=1

Comment: That question is a shining example of a post that *shouldn't* remain visible to anyone.

Answer (score 9):

Be part of the community - ask good questions and give good answers and gain reputation.

You can see deleted posts when you have reputation of +10,000.

Comment: Well this can take more than one year. Approximately I'll need 20 Month. That is a looooong time.

Comment: Better get started, then.

Comment: @rekire - Not if you really want to do it. 200 rep a day = 50 days. And if you can manage getting some bounties and accepted answers, can be shorter than that.

Comment: Sure that is possible, but IMHO to reach daily rep cap is hard work.