# Make it so the asker can see their own deleted questions

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, undelete

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Allow users to be able to see their own deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32675/allow-users-to-be-able-to-see-their-own-deleted-questions)
>   [How do I find questions or answers that I’ve deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/how-do-i-find-questions-or-answers-that-ive-deleted)

Right now the question asker (after a certain amount of rep) can both delete and undelete their own question. The problem I have with this is that it is usually almost impossible to undelete your own question because you can't see it. I propose that we allow questions to be seen by their original poster.

For instance I asked a sorta obvious question and then deleted it. One of the answer-posters suggested I undelete it(by commenting on a different question of mine). Even though I have "permission" to undelete my own question, I do not have permission to view it, hence being capable of undeleting is pointless in this case.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32675/allow-users-to-be-able-to-see-their-own-deleted-questions which was closed as a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/how-do-i-find-questions-or-answers-that-ive-deleted. Voting to reopen the former doesn't sound like a bad idea, though.