# Please let the question's owner see their deleted questions

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Allow users to be able to see their own deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32675/allow-users-to-be-able-to-see-their-own-deleted-questions)
>   [How do I find questions or answers that I've deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/how-do-i-find-questions-or-answers-that-ive-deleted)

I've had a few questions that I deleted afterwards. One was a "quiz" which wasn't received all that well from the community (I deleted it when it received like 10 downvotes and people were in rage of the question). Others contained actual questions that I later found a solution for.

I would like to go back and review those questions, maybe linking it in discussions or otherwise analyzing it. But even their owners don't have any way of listing their deleted questions.

Would there be any chance of implementing this?

Comment: You're either after [Allow users to be able to see their own deleted questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32675/allow-users-to-be-able-to-see-their-own-deleted-questions), if you want to actually see the question that was deleted, or [How do I find questions or answers that I've deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/how-do-i-find-questions-or-answers-that-ive-deleted), if you just want a listing of deleted questions. Either way, I suggest upvoting the feature request you'd like to support.

Comment: Do you want links to your deleted questions? You have four: the one you deleted yesterday, the quiz, a question about community wiki posts, and one about setting widths of HTML table columns dynamically.

Comment: @Michael yeah that would be awesome :)

Comment: OK -- [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058024/obtaining-line-numbers-for-diagnostics-when-writing-a-scripting-language-compiler), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326319/setting-width-of-a-tables-column-dynamically), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284286/answer-made-community-closed), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322007/c-puzzle-what-will-be-output-and-why).