# Show the deleted question to the question creator

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)

Now only users with enough reputation can see deleted questions. It would be good if the question creator can also see them, if they need to remove the question temporary for a quick edit.

Comment: Already declined at: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted). I would pick [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32675/allow-users-to-be-able-to-see-their-own-deleted-questions) to link, but that got a better closure.

Comment: @Grace I have seen that, but there is a difference to that question. That guy requested to see both deleted answers and deleted questions

Comment: @Grace right, that closed question suits better