# Notifications and links associated with removed questions should be removed

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, global-inbox, comment-replies

I got notifications for questions that have been removed as follows. When I clicked the notification links, I got navigated to 404 pages.

[image: screenshot]

The removed questions also still preserve the links as in https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/ shown below.

[image: screenshot]

I think the links and notifications should be removed as well. Giving notification and links to 404 pages seems weird and does not make sense.

---

If moderators make some comments to the deleted questions, I think non-moderators do not need the notification because the notification will end with 404 (page not found) that are useless.

### Last Edit:

I got annoying notification again and again. But I cannot make a response to it. It is a funny feature. It might be the person making the comment did not know that I cannot see his/her comment.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Showing the link to a deleted question in the front page is probably a problem of cached content. As far as I know, deleted questions are not shown in the list of questions, if you are not a moderator.

I find the notifications about answers or comments for deleted questions useful, at least because it's the only way I have to know somebody has added a comment or an answer, and it let me know the question has been deleted. If the deleted question is one of the questions in my favorite list, then I will remove it from my favorite questions.

10k users can still see deleted questions, through the question link; the system should verify if you are the author of the deleted question, a moderator, or a 10k user, and then notify you about a comment on a deleted question, if one of the above conditions is verified.

Comment: The question had been deleted several hours ago, but I got a notification several minutes ago. I don't know how some people (such as Stefan as a TeX moderator) can make a comment for deleted questions. Comments made by Stefan (as a moderator) cannot be read by me and it is useless, right?

Comment: @xport There are circumstances that allow the visibility of comments on deleted answers (as you can always see your own deleted answers on live questions).

Comment: @Grace: If moderators make a comment to a deleted question and I get a notification about it, how can I know their comment if I just see 404 page? So notification is useless in this case.

Comment: If I remember well, moderators can add a comment to deleted posts. Getting a notification for such comments is probably useful in few occasions, for example, when the question that has been deleted is in the list of your favorite questions. Keep in mind that some users can still see deleted questions through the question link.

Comment: @xport I apparently hit enter before my completed comment was written. Whoops. You cannot see deleted questions - normally comments do *not* get shown to you in that circumstance. The last published spec claims that these will be removed from your inbox, but it's honestly not exactly a surprise to me that they are erroneously showing up. Notification is meant purely for deleted answers.

Comment: Or it will be better if the owner of the deleted question can still see it so the owner can see the comments made by moderators.

Comment: @xport [Commonly suggested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32675/allow-users-to-be-able-to-see-their-own-deleted-questions), [commonly declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted). If you support it, though, upvote it! Even a declined suggestion can get reversed if good enough support is shown.