# Voting to undelete by owner

Tags: feature-request, support, deleted-posts, undelete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow users to be able to see their own deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32675/allow-users-to-be-able-to-see-their-own-deleted-questions)

So I assume the following is possible, but I am not sure how:

I just deleted a question of mine (note: I do not actually want it undeleted)) and then moved to a different page. When I try to get back to that page, I get a "This question was voluntarily removed by the author – that's you!" statement, which while true, does not let me undelete it.

However, if the page was left open in my browser, I can undelete it just fine (as no other users were involved in its deletion).

Is there a way to undelete a question of your own? If not, why the inconsistency?

In addition, can we please let users see their own deleted questions? Seems silly that they can't. (Yes I am aware of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32675/allow-users-to-be-able-to-see-their-own-deleted-questions) but I think that the highest voted answer on the first one makes a good point, and the issue should be reopened.

Comment: We should really let users see their own deleted questions. It's a completely random restriction

Comment: I agree, but I feel (though I have not been able to find it) that that is a dupe somewhere. In fact, I am kinda surprised this isn't.

Comment: @soandos: [It is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted). ;)

Comment: It's almost exactly the phrase I said :). [Allow users to be able to see their own deleted questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32675/allow-users-to-be-able-to-see-their-own-deleted-questions)

Comment: It is old, and the high voted answers make a good point I think

Comment: @random, three points: 1, it is a duplicate of what exactly? 2, even if the feature request part is a dupe, it can be removed and the question is still valid (in fact that was the origonal form), and 3, see edit made at the same time as the question was closed.

Comment: It's a duplicate of the question linked at the top. And the fact that you can't see deleted questions, even your own, answers the `[support]` request.

Comment: @CodyGray, that part was removed when I edited the question at the same time as it was closed (the banner and everything was overwritten, as my edit was more substansive)

Comment: You can't undelete something you can't see. From there it's turtles all the way down

Comment: False, the page could already be open. I did it with my question that was last deleted (that you closed). So why the inconstancy?

Comment: So you want to delete a question you posted. But you need to see it first. So you want to see your own deleted in order to vote to undelete it. If you can't get to the page, you can't vote on it.

Comment: But if you are already at the page, then you can. Hence the inconsistency (when the page is first deleted they are redirected to it, and then can see it. From there they can undelete it)