# What role should the "market" or "community" have in deciding if questions are constructive vs. moderation?

Tags: discussion, not-constructive

I think we have a real issue with Moderators closing/removing issues as "Not Constructive", etc., even if they are clearly valued by the market or community.

This has been bothering me for a while, but this morning was the straw that broke the camel's back. I came onto StackOverflow and discovered that a question that I asked several years ago, had received 18 up-votes, and which earned me "Famous Question", had been removed (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77839/what-are-the-best-resources-for-learning-java-books-websites-etc).

Clearly, this question had valued as testified to by the number of views and the up-votes it received. Yet, our moderators substituted their opinion of the question's value for that of the community.

I acknowledge and value the role that moderation plays in making StackOverflow a fantastic and valuable resource. At the same time, I believe when we serve a moderators, we need to inform our decisions and actions by the value the community has put on things.

Should this be automated (i.e. a question with 10K Views can't be removed) or should this be a practice?

On a related note, when a question is pulled, shouldn't there be more feedback on why it was pulled then the message I received?

Comment: [Listen to Your Community, But Don't Let Them Tell You What to Do](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do.html)

Comment: I believe this is a legitimate topic for discussion and that Jeff's post should not be the final answer on this topic. I believe we need to consider the impact of what appear to be caprice and arbitrary actions have on build and developing community.

Comment: A wreck with bodies all over the road, blood everywhere and wrapped cars also draws in the views and rubbernecking. But you can hardly say it's something people cherish.

Comment: It is a legitimate topic for discussion, but it's also one that has been discussed countless times. And frankly, I'm not interested in explaining for yet another time why popularity is _not_ a valid quality metric.

Comment: A weak analogy that does not address the context of this question. A question that was on a related topic and had 10K views over 4+ years is suddenly to be eliminated.

Comment: @Yannis - It is not the sole metric, but it should inform our decisions. As someone who has a decently solid reputation on StackOverflow, I view this as a caprice and arbitrary action that is leaving a bad taste in my mouth. I have attempted to contributed and help out. But someone has decided that this doesn't fit and doesn't even have the courtesy to tell me why or to discuss it with me.

Comment: I've started collecting some of the most common arguments why "shopping list" type questions are a problem here: [Why are "shopping list" questions bad?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809)

Comment: @Jordan Wasn't the question closed? If so, wasn't that a good enough indication that the question would eventually be removed?

Comment: @Pekka - Yet, shopping list questions do provide value and we should not dismiss that value.

Comment: @Jordan Nobody is denying that they are valuable. They just aren't for SO.

Comment: The community consensus here is that they're not a good fit for SO, and I've come around to agreeing.

Comment: If anything it should be curated in that tag's wiki. Because it's wiki material, not Q&A material

Comment: And a good comment from the question itself: `Valuable or not, this question doesn't have a clear and concise answer and can lead to discussion. Some people prefer books, other websites, others in person training. What's effective for one person isn't effective for others. The FAQ for StackOverflow is clear about what type of questions are acceptable on this community. My wife really values questions about knitting, but those are not acceptable here either. A good stackoverflow question will have one definitive answer.`

Comment: @Mysticial - Well, they are one of the questions for which I come to SO to get input upon. In fact, I had three conversation in the last week (one each in India, Singapore, and the US) with three different people in which people expressed frustration to me about this practice. I think we need to can the knee jerk reaction and exercise some judgement here.

Comment: @random - a weak and specious analogy which does not address the question being raised.

Comment: Well, applying some judgement then - where is the real *value* in this question? It took you 10 seconds to come up with it, and most answers are link-only ones with an accompanying sentence to the effect of "this is the best". Where is the substance? It's effectively a list of opinions that some random Internet people with voting rights agree or disagree with. Who will curate it over the years, who will fix broken links?

Comment: @Jordan Well, once you've seen the problems that these questions cause, then you'll think of it from a different point of view. That said you seem completely obstinate about the issue with no intention of shifting your thoughts. So I'm done here.

Comment: "Yet, our moderators substituted their opinion of the question's value for that of the community": `deleted by Mark, ACB, LittleBobbyTables, John Saunders, Andrew Barber` . No moderators were involved in the deletion of this question, just qualified members of the community.

Comment: So, no one has yet to address the question raised here: what role should value placed on a question by the community - as measured via the proxy of views and up-votes - play in deciding if a question is appropriate for SO. I am giving you a concrete situation in which to discuss this and I am getting responses that would get a 'F' in a Logic or Rhetoric 101 class.

Comment: @Jordan well, you're about the 1,000th person to raise that question, so you'll forgive us if we're not inclined to follow instructions to the letter.

Comment: I've already addressed that question @Jordan. No role at all, views and up-votes are an absolutely worthless combination of metrics.

Comment: @Bard Larson - Would love to be able to see the "Who deleted" information, but it is not accessible to me." And if you want, you can substitute "Qualified Users" for "Moderators" in my comment above. The same basic argument stands.

Comment: @Mysticial - Not obstinate, just feeling that no one is addressing the question I posed.

Comment: The quorum had already decided that it's not worth keeping something that is so constantly out of date when they deleted it as a group, not done by a single power munching mod with diamond encrusted teeth

Comment: @Yannis - if your position is correct, that Up-votes and views are absolutely worthless, why do we have them? Perhaps we should remove them, since they have no value. If you are going to act on a data point, then don't collect it. All metrics should be actionable.

Comment: @Jordan Upvotes and views aren't worthless, and they do convey information, it's simply important to understand what information they do convey, and what conclusions we can make as a result of those metrics.  Just because it's one of the few metrics that we have for questions doesn't mean you can use them everywhere.

Comment: @Servy - How should we be weighing them and where should we be applying them?

Comment: @Jordan - You may want to change the overall tone of your question, then. Your very first sentence starts with "I think we have a real issue with Moderators closing/removing issues", which doesn't really apply here. Power has been vested in the community to delete questions like this as a result of the arguments that led to ["Community-led deletionism: a protocol for sanity"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124439/community-led-deletionism-a-protocol-for-sanity).

Comment: @Brad Larson - Thank you for your feedback. Really the first piece of feedback on this question that I felt was helpful. I also apologize, if I was mistaken in my understanding of the process. But even though I asked the question, I could not see who closed it or deleted it.

Comment: That's a fair point - the owner of the question should get to see what happened. Sadly, we here on Meta have asked for this many many times but the SE team won't budge. See eg. [Allow users to be able to see their own deleted questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32675)

Comment: All - Part of the reason I think I was so bothered in this process, is that absolutely no feedback was provided to me. I came onto SO this morning, noticed that one of my questions had been down voted (first time I was ever down voted) and I went to look at the questions. And what I get is a message that it had been deleted. No reason why. No who did it. Just that it was deleted.

Comment: @Jordan - Yeah, the "removed for reasons of moderation" notice isn't the most descriptive. [This feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32675/allow-users-to-be-able-to-see-their-own-deleted-questions) would be helpful here. Deletion of popular questions has been a tricky issue, where it first was too easy for the community to do, so people complained, then it became too hard, so people used moderators as their proxy to delete questions, which also didn't go well. We'll certainly keep debating this.

Comment: I'm one of the most inclusionist of all members on meta but I don't see a compelling case for this question to be undeleted. It doesn't really provide much, if any value at all. On another note, what a terrible analogy, eh @random?

Comment: @BradLarson - Thanks for your feedback and insight into the situation. And part of my confusion about it being deleted by moderators was because it said, "Removed for reasons of moderation".

Comment: @Jordan, I'm not 10k on SO yet.  When I get there if I still remember this I will cast a vote to undelete.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - You stated, "A good stackoverflow question will have one definitive answer." I am an engineer and I know that most engineering problems have multiple equally good solutions depending on context. If we are going to say that a question like, removing it from the field of CS for a moment,  "What is the best type of O-Ring to Use on a Booster" is not a acceptable question, because it has multiple good, solid answers depending on context, we are doing ourselves a disservice.

Answer (score 10):

That post was not closed or deleted by a moderator (note1), but by community members. Your point "this kind of post should not be deleted" can stand or fall on its own merits but your point "community is being overridden by moderators" doesn't apply here.

[image]

That said, 5 people deleted it and 5 can undelete it, which I predict will happen by the time I click Submit on this answer. At first thought, I would support a historical lock on it, but since this prevents updating, I am not so sure now. Not all good information has to live here. Perhaps your own web site or blog would be a better home for such a list?

Note 1: ok fine, a diamond was part of closing, but was the 5th vote so it would have closed without the diamond powers.

Comment: How can it be undeleted if you can no longer see the question?

Comment: @Jordan 10k users can see the question and vote to undelete it. It even shows up in a 10k list of "recently deleted" questions.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - Even though I asked the question, I can't see any feedback on it. I can't see the messages in the message above. Should we be providing better feedback to people on why an action was taken.

Comment: @Jordan You got that feedback when the question was closed. The 10k users who can vote to undelete it can also see the entire question, its answers, comments, and close/delete notices.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - The two events were separated in time substantially (17 months). Couple that with the fact that I can't see anything about this question now (I can't see the information about it that is in this question above).

Comment: The difference between moderators and high reputation users is becoming an increasing source of confusion it seems. Though, the distinction seems quite clear as presented. I'm not sure if it's rampant enough to open a discussion for yet, but I have noticed several people in the last few weeks (in comments) remarking that they felt like a 'moderator' overstepped, yet no mods were involved.

Answer (score 8):

*(I started this as a comment, but it just got too unwieldly, so I've posted it here instead)*

I'll chime in here since I cast one of the delete votes.

Yes, your question may have had many upvotes, and yes it may have had many views, but SO has changed over the years in what is acceptable or not.

The question is clearly is not constructive, so it was closed.  Then what?

If the question sticks around, users get the impression these kind of questions are valid.  Fine, then add a historical lock to it.

So now you've got a question that can still be found with Google searches, a question that will slowly get more and more outdated since it can't be updated anymore.

If I voted incorrectly, or if I did something wrong, I'll be the first to aplogize, but that's my reasoning for it, and I stand by it.

Comment: Fair enough, and I'm starting to think I'm going to cast my delete vote if it gets undeleted.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - So, we decide something is non constructive, even though it had views and up-votes, and lock it. Then it becomes out of date, since no one can update it. So we delete.  Seems  like a self-fulfilling path to me.

Comment: @Jordan Once locked, it can't be deleted. That's the point of the historical lock: Keep it from being deleted, but mark it as "not an appropriate question to ask anymore"

Comment: @Jordan - I get it, you're upset, but you seem to be ignoring the fact that the question is no longer appropriate for Stack Overflow.  Your question is over four years old, and really doesn't have that many upvotes for a question that old.  Just because a question got upvotes four years ago doesn't mean it would get upvotes today.  Honestly, I would have downvoted it and voted to close it in a heartbeat if you had asked the question today.  Upvotes on years-old-questions is not a good metric to judge questions, the content should be judged.

Comment: ... plus it isn't even that much of a question. I've seen works of *genius* deleted that this paltry list doesn't even begin to compare to.

Answer (score -2):

That post should be undeleted, they can lock it like they've done with other posts now considered off-topic/non-constructive, but it shouldn't have been taken away.

Comment: I agree with you. While I had a problem with it being locked, someone is clearly not making an informed decision in deleting someone that has been up for 4+ years, had a large number of upvotes (can't tell you because I can't see it anymore), and which had 10K views.

Comment: @Jordan It doesn't actually have very many upvotes for a question that old of that type, and a *very* low vote per view ratio...

Comment: @Jordan: FYI: It had 19 upvotes, 1 downvote, and ~18000 views upon its deletion.

Comment: @DavidRobinson - All information I cannot see, since I can't see the Question any longer, since I am not a 10K.