# Add advanced search option for finding deleted posts

Tags: feature-request, search, 10k-tools, deleted-posts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have an isdeleted:1 search option/operator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41130/can-we-have-an-isdeleted1-search-option-operator)

Let's add the Advanced Search option of **isdeleted:1**, so that for example I could search for all my deleted posts, i.e. **user:me isdeleted:1**.

I think this would be a good addition to the Advanced Search operators, even if it is only useful for 10k users.

Comment: @Zombie, aaggghh, I searched and searched, but didn't think of searching for 'isdeleted' (or I just clutzed out and missed it).  I'll vote to close also.  At least maybe the original will get some votes now.  The new 'reqs' tab only shows the highest voted ones, so those low-voted ones don't get in front of people.

Comment: While this post should be closed, please don't delete it, so that it will be easier to find in searches in the future.