# As a 2K user, what am I seeing when I search for deleted:1?

Tags: support, deleted-posts

I would expect searching for `deleted:1` to return no results here as I don't have the rep to view deleted posts, however I get loads of results returned, none of them appear to be deleted, nor have 'deleted' (the word) within the content.

[image]

What I actually seeing when I search for `deleted:1`?

Comment: Does that even exist as a search option?

Comment: Well when I search 'deleted:1' on ux.stackexchange (where I am a mod) I get returned all the deleted posts, but the same query here and other SE sites I get returned actual posts.

Comment: Seems related to [Can we have an isdeleted:1 search option/operator?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41130/can-we-have-an-isdeleted1-search-option-operator) with status-declined.

Comment: I believe the default behavior of the search is to ignore something that doesn't exist as a criteria, or something you don't have privileges to see.  Searching for `votes:2q34` returns all questions (effectively ignoring the filter since it doesn't make sense), whereas searching for `votes:234` returns 64 questions (everything with more than 234 votes).  Just a guess though based on my experiences, so I'm not confident enough to make this an answer.

Comment: @BoPersson: Yeah, I saw that one and the fact it was status:declined just confused me even more. I am clearly seeing *something* but whether or not it's related to my search query I'm not convinced.

Comment: as a 16k user i am seeing this http://i.stack.imgur.com/OEEx1.png

Comment: @NullPointer: That is... even more confusing.

Comment: Just to follow up my earlier comment, searching for an unrecognized filter such as `unicorns:yes` will return zero because it is searching for the exact string of "unicorns:yes" rather than treating "unicorns" as a filter and "yes" as the criterion.

Comment: @Bart - Yes, but I believe it's only enabled for moderators, not even 20k users. At least it was that way when I got elected.

Comment: @BradLarson Okay, could very well be the case. For me on Meta it does nothing.

Answer (score 9):

[@psubsee2003](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176608/as-a-2k-user-what-am-i-seeing-when-i-search-for-deleted1#comment530295_176608) is describing what I noticed too: When a option is ignored, and it is the only option used to search, the search returns all the posts. The difference with "deleted:" and other options, is that when other options are ignored you notice that.

For example, if I use "votes:2" the result page shows this.

> [image: screenshot]

If I use "votes:q123" the result page doesn't show any option as being used for the search.

> [image: screenshot]

With "deleted:1" there isn't any way to know if the option is applied, or not. I can know it from the background shown for the posts.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

When I use "deleted:1" or "votes:q123" on this site, I get 135,086 results in both the cases; when I use "user:me votes:q123" or "user:me" on the same site, I get 1,185 results in both the cases.

I am moderator on *Drupal Answers*, and on that site I am allowed to search for deleted answers.