# How to find the set of own deleted answers

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

Is there any way to find the set of answers that I answered first but deleted later for some reason?

Comment: Nope, there is not. You can see them if you remember the question you posted them to, but there is no list.

Comment: See [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645)

Comment: You have 12 such answers. The direct answer to your question is "No, without assistance from a moderator"; is there a particular answer you want or would you like all of them to be linked from here?

Comment: Mods can do a search for: `is:answer deleted:yes user:me`

Comment: Doesn't the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) show deleted stuff?

Comment: @mmyers Your question is like replying to someone who's lost there keys with "well, where did you last have them?" - save for the list offering part, of course.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: With the slight difference that I have X-ray vision and can find them every set of keys in the entire neighborhood.

Comment: Which in the case of deletions here of a single individual _would_ largely be useful.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Only if the post was still visible when the data dump was last refreshed.

Comment: @mmyers Wait! So the data explorer _doesnt_ connect to the database? It only uses the last data dump? Like the torrent downloads?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: The data explorer uses a sanitized data set just like the data dump.