# Allow people to continue to see favorited but closed and deleted posts

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

I recently had a post deleted off SO that I referred to quite a bit about the 'Best ASCII table'.  Regardless of the awful rational behind having it deleted, I really liked having that at my fingertips and I think a lot of other people did to because it was favorited and viewed by lots of folks.  It's not like a boat programming question and it was a wiki so I wasn't rep-mongering.

I just figured that like like a good C++ book, SO needs an ASCII table, anyway I don't see a reason why I shouldn't be able to see it just because I'm not virile enough to get 10000 rep.  I guess I could just ask the question again and hope that a more enlightened crowd won't close it on me.

Comment: Agree on all points. Some questions, for whatever reason, turn out to be quite contentious, and the exclusionists seem to have an edge over such questions unless they get locked by a moderator. You need to get 10000 rep, though, if you want to see deleted questions.

Comment: Kind of related to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/how-do-i-find-questions-or-answers-that-ive-deleted -- I would imagine that that feature-request would be implemented before what's being proposed here since it only deals with *self* posts, not *other people's* posts. Basically what you're asking for here is 10k privileges on the favourite questions, which I seriously doubt will happen.

Comment: Yeah, probably too much to ask, although it is pretty annoying to have to be exceedingly smart or devoted to get access to your 'own' content

Comment: @Jon Seigel:  As a 10K+ SO user, I have a lot more privileges than just reading deleted questions; I can vote to undelete, for example.  Seeing deleted questions and answers is something of a side effect (and one I sometimes find annoying).

Comment: @David: Yeah, I meant a *subset* of 10k privileges (I thought that was obvious, sorry).

Comment: @Jon Siegel:  I may not have been clear.  What I meant was that, just because some ability is part of the 10K+ package, I don't see why it couldn't be pulled out and allotted separately under specific circumstances.  It wouldn't be granting any of the 10K+ decisions or special tools.

Comment: @David: Okay, I understand now. I still think that being able to see *other people's* deleted questions should be reserved for 10k, though.