# Extend the visibility of the deleted questions to users who favorite

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, visibility

I don't know why the visibility of the deleted questions is limited to 10k+ users, but I suppose it's done to help people to find the right answers and not waste their time on bad questions.

If my supposition is correct, the visibility of the deleted questions could be extended to the users who have starred the question, because for them it's obviously useful and maybe it's useful also to the question owner too.

Probably the implementation of this might be a little messy, but it could be a nice feature. (I suppose that actually, connected to the visibility of their deleted questions, there are other features that must be limited to the 10k+ users)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49183/ and as linked from that by Jon, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/365/why-should-10k-rep-users-view-self-deleted-answers

Answer (score 3):

As far as the site content is concerned, those posts are gone. The don't exist. It doesn't make sense to reference them.

The only reason deleted posts are visible to 10K users is to provide historical context to help with moderation. ***Not*** to provide additional content.

Comment: That sounds like if Judges made all past cases inaccessible to the public, yet used those cases to determine the verdict of future cases. It's a bit backwards

Comment: Nothing so nefarious. There might be links to deleted posts that no longer make sense. To fix those posts, you need a sense of context. Besides, 10K users have virtually no "judging" capabilities that 3K users don't have.

Comment: I understand what you mean but the contents are still there, no effort.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I need to remark: it also disables the possibility of their usage in a debate around the rightfulness of a delete/close action.

Comment: @peterh Closed is not deleted. Closed questions are still visible for the use case you described. Closed questions should not be deleted unless they have either been closed for awhile or there is something *egregiously* wrong with the post in the first place.