# Can I get a copy of my recently deleted question and associated answers?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find questions or answers that I’ve deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/how-do-i-find-questions-or-answers-that-ive-deleted)

Is there some place I can go to fetch a deleted question?

Comment: Was it the Knuth one? There weren't any specific answers.

Comment: The Knuth one in particular, but in general it seems pretty bad that it's beyond my control to recover my deathless prose so I can put it somewhere else.  I should be able to see it in from the tools menu, so I'll give that a go.  special note for you, I'll flag this question for your attention.

Comment: why don't you just mention "@Marc" in your instead of flagging? That way only he'll be notified instead of all mods...

Comment: I've sent you a copy by e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only see your deleted questions if you're 10k.

Comment: Even then they're not displayed on your profile.