# Retrieving a deleted Stack Overflow question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Hello...I deleted one of my Stack Overflow questions (it was a tumbleweed question).  However, I'd like to re-instate it in case someone may eventually have an answer.  Is there a way/process  to "un-delete" a question on Stack Overflow?  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you still know the question's URL (like if you have a bookmark or find it in your browser history) you can go there and just click "undelete" to get the question back.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest posting the deleted question again, this will will have the added benefit, of bumping it back up, which will probably mean it will be viewed by many people who did not see it before.

Comment: But he brings up a valid point. What if the question was long and you don't want to rewrite it again?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't directly possible. A mail to team@stackoverflow.com is the best you could do.

I'd however consider to open a [`[feature-request]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) right here to make deleted questions visible in your own question history (and only when you're the one who views the questions (and maybe diamond moderators as well)) with a different background color as already is done for deleted answers.

Comment: Such a request already exists (and is quite old): [How do I find questions or answers that I’ve deleted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/how-do-i-find-questions-or-answers-that-ive-deleted)