# Is there a way to view my own deleted questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find questions or answers that I've deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/how-do-i-find-questions-or-answers-that-ive-deleted)

Some of my questions were closed and deleted on Stack Overflow for being too subjective. I would like to resurrect them on http://programmers.stackexchange.com. Is there any way I can view them?

Comment: Users with 10K+ rep can view deleted questions and their content.

Comment: Following Marc's advice from http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/how-do-i-find-questions-or-answers-that-ive-deleted, flag a post for moderator attention and ask for an email readout of all of the question IDs for your deleted questions. However, since you aren't 10k, you still won't be able to see them, in which case it might require getting copies of them sent to you via email. But there's naught short of that which can be done easily.

Comment: 10k users can also find questions that weren't deleted by the author with some level of ease using the deleted questions list, but this only works for questions that were deleted within 30 days.