# Is there any way to know when something you've posted has been deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-posts

Sometimes when I come across posts that are wrong / have errors I'll post a comment to the author rather than downvoting immediately, to give them a chance to fix the problem / retract the post.

If the author appears to be offline, then I might give it a day, then revisit the post to see what the outcome was.  Usually, I drive the re-review from my comments activity.  I also use my comments activity to track back to interesting questions / posts.

Sometimes the comments disappear (I'm assuming because the posts that have been commented on have been deleted).

Is there any way to get notification that something you've written has been deleted + why?

Other scenarios where this would be useful include:

- An OP posted additional information in an answer to their own question, rather than editing their question.  I commented on the answer.  When the post was eventually deleted, the comments went with it.
- I've had an answer deleted in the past, I don't remember getting notification about it (although I may have done, it was a while ago).  Obviously knowing something has been deleted and why gives me the best chance of avoiding the same mistake in the future.

Comment: At 10k tools, there is recently deleted list.

Comment: @YOU: but apart from that, there's no other way.

Comment: Well, Imm, may be save /reputation audit page and diff later on?

Comment: Related: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) and [How do I find questions or answers that I've deleted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/how-do-i-find-questions-or-answers-that-ive-deleted). You might also want to subscribe to your own activity feed: an RSS/Atom reader can show you history that is no longer available on the site, and might even give you options to mark some of your own activities for later reference.

Comment: @Arjan: Do you want to post this as an answer and I'll accept it?  I've subscribed to my user feed as a way of tracking stuff and changed my behaviour, so I'll downvote + comment, then go back and check the post to see if it's been updated later and possibly remove the downvote.  If the post gets deleted then it's more obvious because the downvote (which there's less of than comments) disappears.