# Accessing deleted questions to improve and get out of question ban

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, post-ban

How can I view questions that have been deleted? I'd like to be able to access them so I can improve them to get out of my question ban ([as said here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th/86998#86998)), but I'm not able to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [see your deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13203/187824). Go to your [questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3240414/kalyanakumar619?tab=questions). Here you can see the link of *deleted recent questions*. Here you can see your deleted questions that were posted in the past 60 days.

Comment: is it [60 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/221351) or 90 days, can you plz confirm...

Comment: @CRUSADER - I have asked the SE dev for this to confirm.

Comment: It is 60 days. That is, only posts that have been posted up to 60 days ago.

Comment: @Oded Thanks for clearing the confusion here.